# Problems with double values in subclass

Tags: java

I am making a survey that answers Questions using a double but i am getting a error in my extended class.

The super class:

```
import java.io.Serializable; 

public abstract class Question implements Serializable
{        
    protected String question;
    protected int maxResponses;
    protected int numResponses;

    public Question(String q, int m)
    {
        question = q;
        maxResponses = m;
        numResponses = 0;
    }

    public abstract void askQuestion();       
    public abstract void displayResults();        
}
```

and here is my extended class which is DoubleQuestions:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoubleQuestions extends Question 
{
  private double[] responses;
  public DoubleQuestions(double q, int m)
  {
    super(q,m); // ERROR: constructor Question in class Question cannot be applied to given types;
    responses = new double[m];
  }

  @Override
  public void askQuestion()
  {
    double response;            
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(question + " ");
    input.nextLine(); //still have to "eat" the current response          
    response = input.nextLine(); // ERROR: incompatible types
    responses[numResponses] = response;
    numResponses++;
  }
  @Override
  public void displayResults()
  {
     System.out.println(question);
     for(int i = 0; i < numResponses;i++)
       System.out.println(responses[i]);
     }        
   }
```

Errors are marked as comments in source code.

Comment: Can you plz metion what error are you getting??

Comment: Java is not Javascript. One tag is enough.

Comment: there is no lines 23 and 34 for us.... we need the error msg

Comment: As others have indicated, please specify what lines 23 and 34 are as well as the exact text of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base constructor expects a string as first argument. You intend to call it using a double value.

But java doesn't convert double to string automatically.

You want to use Double.toString() for example,to rework your code like this:

```
super(Double.toString(q),
```

The other problem: `nextLine()` returns a **String**, not double. Thus you can't assign to a double value.

The real answer here: **read** documentation about the classes your are using; you will find for example that Scanner has a method `nextDouble()` which you could call instead.

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: Let OP first correct mistake of not showing error to us. We can catch the error by our own but OP should have mentioned that.

Comment: Im sorry i am a little new to this and im trying to self teach so can you tell me where exactly should I add that

Comment: @GhostCat ok that fixed the first error i have but do you know how i can fix the other error which is  this line :response = input.nextLine();

Comment: Thank you GhostCat i really appreciate the help the code is all good now

Comment: @luigi - that one is addressed by Blasanka's answer

Comment: sure @GhostCat. :-)

Comment: @jackjay Thank you. Appreciate your regards for quality!

Answer (score 1):

One error is in your `askQuestion` method. You are assigning `String value to a`double`variable.`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double response;            
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("question" + " ");
    input.nextLine(); //still have to "eat" the current response          
    response = input.nextLine(); 
}
```

look at this `double response;` it is a double and you assigning `input.nextLine()`, which is `String`.

To solve this:

```
response = input.nextDouble();
```

Get input as double or change `response` variable data type to `String`.

And the second error in your `super()`. Because you are passing `double` value and in the parent class constructor you are taking it as `String`.

child class constructor

```
public DoubleQuestions(double q, int m)
{
      super(q,m);
      responses = new double[m];
}
```

parent class constructor

```
public Question(String q, int m)
{
    question = q;
    maxResponses = m;
    numResponses = 0;
}
```

To solve this you can overload the constructor in parent class or pass `q` value as `String`.

Like this:

```
super(q+"",m);
```

**UPDATE:**

This `q+""` concatenation is the easiest one,

But performance wise it is not good,

`"" + q` is slower as shown above in `super()`. `Double.toString(q)` is better.

Comment: do you know how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

You got your parameters messed up in the method: DoubleQuestions, change it to:

```
public DoubleQuestions(String q, int m)
```

Remember: You have to pass the same types of variables in a situation where there's class inheritance.

Comment: I disagree - it's perfectly acceptable for "child" class constructors to take different arguments than the "parent" class. The problem is the `super` call.

Comment: I agree with the method that you posted, I just think it's way more convenient to have the same types of variables, in class inheritance the same. It makes debugging more easy and efficient and helps the programmer stay out of unnecessary type conversions.